# how to edit a specific element in json file using gson

Tags: java, json, multithreading, gson

I am creating a pause resume mechanism for a download manager. I want to write amount of bytes read to a `json` file after every 5 sec (Auto saving mechanism).

1) So how can edit a specific element in json without rewriting whole json file.

2) Will that method be thread safe? Lets suppose I have a single `json` file and multiple threads would be updating different elements of that same json. 
So how this can be done in using `gson`. Do i need a `producer consumer` approach or some thing simple can be done?

Comment: just read the json -> convert to java object -> apply changes -> recreate the json again -> finally write in the file back. All the steps should be done in a transaction to avoid multiple threads issues.

Comment: @user3218114 But will this write only the changed part to file or will it wrote whole json file again?